# Separate WCF Service Instance For Different Host Instance and Endpoint?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have two applications using the same wcf service instance.  These two applications will always be started in pairs, so I can have a second, third, or fourth instance of these two.  Does this mean I need to have one wcf service being hosted by say a Windows Service, IIS, or console app using a common endpoint address for all four of the instance pairs?  Or if I dynamically hardcode the endpoint addresses such that each individual pair has it's own and self host in one of the two applications, does that mean each pair has access to it's own service?

I could probably benchtop test this, but I figure someone with experience could save me quite a bit of coding time just trying to figure it out.

**Update (for clarity):**

The reason for this question is due to the particular situation I'm working with.  The scenario is that the two applications involve one client exe that I am developing and a third-party exe that I have no control over.  I can develop a dll that the third-party exe can load.  Between my third-party app dll and the client exe the WCF service is intended to bridge the process space to allow the two to communicate transaction information.  This will allow the client exe to control the third-party exe and the files it manages.

Comment: difficult to answer without a more complete description, (is the service being used only to communicate between the two applications, is the service stateful? is this an appserver with many clients? are we talking duplex channels?) But i wonder if you couldn't share the same service/endpoint and have it pass messages that have an associated application-pair id so the service can route them appropriately?

Comment: I'm basically applying the WCF concepts as I learn, so not sure what service stateful means.  Yes though.  It is used to communicate information between two applications.  And it does use duplex channels because to accomplish this.  It's basically one application using a service to manage transaction in another application.

Comment: Right now I do have a centralized service being hosted by a third host application.  It works great, but then I got to wondering if it would be best to manage the two in pairs versus a centralized service for any number of pairs.  This prompted the question, if I self-host within one application and use a separate endpoint (with the address being dynamic but understandable only between the two applications per pair), does that create a separate service instance per pair?  Or am I misunderstanding how the service instance is created?

Comment: It is recommended that you post clarifications in the body of the question.

Comment: Service lifetime (session) and endpoints are separate issues. A stateful service is one that "remembers" information between calls.

Answer (score 1):

This is partly an answer partly a long comment. :)

One way to think of a WCF service is that it passes messages back and forth between two separate applications. At a very general level, although there are plenty of good reasons to make a stateful service, it is generally accepted that it is better to be stateless. This means that each time you call it you pass all the info it needs to do what it does, and the service does not need to remember what was done earlier.

The fact that you are worried about separate instances suggests to me that your service has state. I do not think multiple endpoints is the way to go for your situation.

I would suggest that when an application "pair" starts up the first thing it could do would be to request a unique ID from the service. From that point on all messages to the service would contain this ID and the service would process them accordingly. If the service application is maintaining state it would use this ID as a key to identify what information to access to process the call.

At this point you end up with One service application on one server and multiple client applications which is how most WCF systems are designed.

Updated, I think you should google "WCF: Instance Management Per-Call and Per-Session"
Your client should be able to open a connection from the client and keep it open. WCF will automagically create a new instance on the server for you. This would mean you don't need the "application pair ID" but you would need to keep the session open.

Comment: Okay, that's how it's designed now. I basically created a unique, but generic, ID object that uses a Guid to generate the actual ID value. Then I have the one service application and server application. This morning I was taking a fresh look at its design and got to wondering if maybe what I was doing would be better by self-hosting in one of the client apps with a unique endpoint address per application "pair". The thought was maybe that would reduce the need of using an ID, but I wasn't sure if this was even possible or practiced.  Sounds like I just need to stick with what I have.

Comment: Btw... I really appreciate your insight. Being new to WCF, it's just as easy to question best practices as it is how it works. Out of curiousity though, is it possible to self-host a separate instance of the service using a more dynamic endpoint address that only the application "pair" would know? That would allow it to be stateless, whereas just as you explained it is stateful so that it can track who's communicating with whom.

Comment: I dont understand why you need a pair of applications, why do you  need more than one WCF app, It seems to me you are on the wrong track there. Are you saying the app logic would be different for each seperate wcf app?, updating my answer to deal with sessions.

Comment: I don't have a choice. One of the two applications is a third-party exe that I have no control over.  I can, however, develop a dll that the third-party application is capable of loading.  The WCF service allows me to control and manage the third-party application (and the files it manages) from another, external application, thus the application "pair" (a dll loaded in a third-party app and a client exe).  I'll update the question for clarity, but didn't put it in there at first because I was afraid to confuse the question.

Comment: actually now it makes sense